# Using XDebug in UEStudio for PHP debugging

Tags: php, debugging, xdebug

I've just downloaded the latest version of UEStudio 09 and am trying out the integrated XDebug features.

I've got xdebug installed, and have verified that via my php_info(). I've written a very basic script to test it out:

```
1:  <?php
2:  $x = 5;
3:  $y = $x + 1;
4:  $z = 10;
5:  while ($z--) {
6:      echo $x, $y, "<br />\n";
7:  }
```

I've then started the debugging session and get this message in my output window:

```
Client: Listening for connection...
```

I've added a breakpoint on line 4, just to test it out. I then open the file in my browser with the special url parameter:

```
http://localhost/uetest/index.php?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=test
```

The script runs normally and it doesn't stop for debugging or anything. The output is this:

```
Client: Listening for connection...
Client: Connection accepted
Client: Initializing session
==============================
Debug Engine Name: Xdebug
Debug Engine Version: 2.0.3
Protocol Version: 1.0
==============================
Client: Session active
Client Command: Step Into
Client: Exiting debug session
Script completed without errors
```

If I visit `http://localhost:9000/uetest/index.php` then UEStudio says "Connection accepted", but from there nothing happens! The script never completes in the browser, and then finally UEStudio crashes.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Last week I evaluated UEStudio as a replacement for Zend Studio 5.5. I setup my XDebug configuration as follows and got it working:

```
[XDebug]
zend_extension_ts=./ext/php_xdebug.dll
xdebug.profiler_enable=0
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger=1
xdebug.profiler_output_dir=d:/
xdebug.profiler_output_name=timestamp
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_autostart=0
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_host=localhost 
xdebug.idekey=debug
```

I had to add several settings to my php.ini to get it working. Above is the resulting configuration. Also, I installed XDebug Helper Firefox addon to start debugging right from Firefox. Very convenient.

Answer (score 0):

Many years ago I used xdebug but recently I've been using the Zend Debugger so I can't remember off hand what I did to get the xdebug.dll to work. I do remember, however, that I did need to add a few entries into the php.ini. The entries that I have for the Zend Debugger are:

For Linux:

```
[Zend]
zend_extension=/usr/lib/php5/20060613+lfs/ZendDebugger.so
zend_debugger.allow_hosts=127.0.0.1
zend_debugger.expose_remotely=always
```

For Windows:

```
[Zend]
zend_extension_ts="c:/php/ext/ZendDebugger.dll"
zend_debugger.allow_hosts=127.0.0.1
zend_debugger.expose_remotely=always
```

A Google search for "php xdebug php.ini" took me here:

http://devzone.zend.com/article/2930-Debugging-PHP-applications-with-xdebug

Which suggests:

```
xdebug.remote_enable=On
xdebug.remote_host="localhost"
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_handler="dbgp"
```

for xdebug.

Hope this helps.